# How to add the selected element to the page?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a list of news that comes from the API on the screen.
Output code for one card with news(I shortened the code and left only the necessary):

```
Widget customListTile(Article article, BuildContext context) {
final newsController = Get.put(FavoritesController());
  return InkWell(
    Container(
            child:Row(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  article.source.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      newsController.addNews(article);
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
              ]
            )
          ),
  );
}
```

There is an icon, when clicked, the addNews() function is called.And there is a controller code where there is this function:

```
class FavoritesController extends GetxController {

  var _news = {}.obs;

  void addNews(Article article) {
   if(_news.containsKey(article)) {
      
     }
  }

  get news => _news;
}
```

I need when clicking on the icon, the news was added to a separate Saved page.
How to write a function for adding news in a controller? And did I write the code correctly? Can you please tell me how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you either use

```
.obs
```

or

```
GetxController function update()
```

There is no need to change your code tho because this will work as well but you're not using GetxController correctly in this case.

Let's focus on the `.obs`

Move the

Now, make a ListView that is wrapped with Obx(() => ...) which uses the news obs.

```
Obx(() {
  return ListView(
    children: Get.find<FavoritesController>().news.map((e) => customListTile(e)).toList(),
  );
});
```

Let's move to the `addNews` function.

When you add an article use the update function.

```
 if(_news.containsKey(article)) {
   _news.update((e) => e[key]=value);
 }
```

Also, move

`final newsController = Get.put(FavoritesController());`

outside of this function, even though is not necessary, it makes no sense for it to be there.

Comment: Where should i use Obx(() {..}? In the file with FavoritesController class?

Comment: Where you're using `customListTile` when building the list